# Access denied, but content is set to public

Tags: google-bigquery

Trying to use BigQuery within my application. I'm getting this error, and I'm not sure why. Any feedback on next steps. Things are set to "public" so it's not a GS access denied message.

```
{"kind"=>"bigquery#job", "etag"=>"\"GwY6LdvTeqT4YdFN4PyQz2tXZdQ/0q_--jbh-hteL0v2xbStstv0h40\"", "id"=>"tempusgroup.com:omagoog:job_7d07a09c108a49f686c7580461816048", "selfLink"=>"https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/tempusgroup.com:omagoog/jobs/job_7d07a09c108a49f686c7580461816048", "jobReference"=>{"projectId"=>"tempusgroup.com:omagoog", "jobId"=>"job_7d07a09c108a49f686c7580461816048"}, "configuration"=>{"load"=>{"sourceUris"=>["gs://omaload/mentions_94354.utf-8.bigquery"], "schema"=>{"fields"=>[{"name"=>"created_at", "type"=>"STRING"}, {"name"=>"keyword", "type"=>"STRING"}, {"name"=>"phrases", "type"=>"RECORD", "mode"=>"REPEATED", "fields"=>[{"name"=>"phrase", "type"=>"STRING"}]}]}, "destinationTable"=>{"projectId"=>"tempusgroup.com:omagoog", "datasetId"=>"omadata", "tableId"=>"mentions_test"}, "createDisposition"=>"CREATE_IF_NEEDED", "sourceFormat"=>"NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON"}}, "status"=>{"state"=>"DONE", "errorResult"=>{"reason"=>"accessDenied", "message"=>"Access Denied: File gs://omaload/mentions_94354.utf-8.bigquery: Access Denied"}, "errors"=>[{"reason"=>"accessDenied", "message"=>"Access Denied: File gs://omaload/mentions_94354.utf-8.bigquery: Access Denied"}]}, "statistics"=>{"startTime"=>"1358707905511", "endTime"=>"1358707905511"}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The google storage file in the job doesn't seem to be public:

```
$ gsutil cat gs://omaload/mentions_94354.utf-8.bigquery | head
GSResponseError:: status=403, code=None, reason=Forbidden.
```